# Telerik RadGrid: My "delete record" checkbox column is read only. How can I fix this?

Tags: telerik, radgrid

Here's my grid:

```
<telerik:RadGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ID="grdUsers" DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1" AllowSorting="True" runat="server" GridLines="None" Skin="Office2007">
    <HeaderContextMenu CssClass="GridContextMenu GridContextMenu_Default"></HeaderContextMenu>
    <MasterTableView TableLayout="Fixed" DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1">
        <CommandItemSettings ExportToPdfText="Export to Pdf"></CommandItemSettings>
        <RowIndicatorColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter RowIndicator column"></RowIndicatorColumn>
        <ExpandCollapseColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter ExpandColumn column"></ExpandCollapseColumn>
        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="FirstName" DataField="FirstName" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="FirstName" HeaderStyle-Width="150"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="LastName" HeaderStyle-Width="150" DataField="LastName" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="LastName"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Email" DataField="Email" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Email"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn HeaderText="Delete?" HeaderStyle-Width="60" ReadOnly="false"></telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn>
        </Columns>
        <EditFormSettings>
            <EditColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter EditCommandColumn column"></EditColumn>
        </EditFormSettings>
    </MasterTableView>
    <FilterMenu EnableImageSprites="False"></FilterMenu>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

As you can see, I have a `GridCheckBoxColumn` at the end that I would like the users to be able to select a few records and then click another button to delete them. The problem is that the check boxes are all disabled even though I set the `ReadOnly` property to false.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the GridCheckBoxColumn incorrectly.  It **must** be bound to a datafield just like a GridBoundColumn.  In your case, you need to place a CheckBox in an ItemTemplate of a GridTemplateColumn.  This will achieve your desired result.

Here is a link from Telerik going through the entire process: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet/grid/grddeletegriditemsdependingoncheckboxstate.html